# Setting up Nexus npm : null pointer exception while uploading tar file on dashboard

Tags: npm, nexus

While trying to upload a simple js bundle I am receiving the following error stack trace when I am viewing the logger on nexus dashboard :

```
2018-06-13 16:31:16,284-0400 ERROR [qtp139199987-18792] admin org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet - Failed to invoke action method: coreui_Upload.doUpload, java-method: org.sonatype.nexus.coreui.UploadComponentComponent.doUpload
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
at com.sonatype.nexus.repository.npm.internal.NpmPackageId.parse(NpmPackageId.java:129)
at com.sonatype.nexus.repository.npm.internal.NpmMetadataUtils.createRepositoryPath(NpmMetadataUtils.java:195)
at com.sonatype.nexus.repository.npm.NpmUploadHandler.lambda$0(NpmUploadHandler.java:84)
at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.OperationPoint.proceed(OperationPoint.java:64)
at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionalWrapper.proceedWithTransaction(TransactionalWrapper.java:56)
at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.transactional(Operations.java:200).....
```

Comment: Something seems wrong with the package/package.json file in the bundle, looks like it has an invalid (or missing) name.

Answer (score 1):

Steps To Take while setting up Nexus with npm :

**Configuration**

1. Download the Nexus OSS [here](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype)
2. Extract the tar file and start cd /NEXUS_FOLDER/nexus ./bin/nexus start
3. Open browser type http://localhost:8081/ . Sign in (Default username=admin/password=admin123)
4. Click Settings -> Repositories -> Create Repository

*How repositories work : * There are three types of repositories :

- Hosted Repositories : Repositories hosted by nexus. (your internal libraries).

  5. Create Repository -> Select npm(hosted) -> Enter name -> Allow redeploy -> Create Repository
- Proxy Repositories : In npm you cannot download packages from different repository servers. So, to download public npm packages you'll have to create a proxy server.

  6. Create Repository -> Select npm(proxy) -> Enter name -> Remote storage -> Enter http://registry.npmjs.org -> Save
- Group Repositories : Group repositories allow you to combine multiple repositories and other repository groups of the same repository format in a single repository group. This single group and the associated URL can then be used as a single access point to all components in a specific format sourced from an number of repositories.

  7. Create Repository -> Select npm(group) -> Member repositories -> Add the two previously created repositories -> Save
  8. Settings -> On left menu -> Realms -> Add npm Bearer Token Realm to active

**Pushing package to repository**

9. Now go to root of project folder type npm init -> create package json -> enter name/version value
10. On terminal at root of project folder type: npm set registry http://localhost:8081/repository/[your-hosted-repo-name]/
11. npm adduser --registry=http://localhost:8081/repository/[your-hosted-repo-name]. Type username/password/email(default: admin/admin123/[your email])
12. npm publish --registry http://localhost:8081/repository/[your-hosted-repo-name].
13. You can now see your package under repositories on Nexus dashboard.

**Pulling your package**

14. Create .npmrc at root of project folder with values :

registry=http://ec2-34-229-205-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8082/repository/[your-nexus-group-repo-name]/

email=your email

_auth=YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM= (generate using : $echo -n 'admin:admin123' | openssl base64)

15. In package.json

    "dependencies": {
        "your-project-name" : "1.0.0"
      }
16. npm install
17. You can now see your package under node_modules/

Comment: after searching for a long time finally something useful, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was called in to diagnose an issue like this, and it ended up being that the .tgz file being loaded was not in fact a .tar.gz at all (it was a renamed zip!).  Their code that parses package.json tries to load in a .tar.gz stream, but if that fails and an exception is thrown for any reason it simply logs an error "Error occurred while processing package.json, returning empty map to continue" and then returns an empty map.  The first thing it does after loading package.json is call createRepositoryPath with the name and version from the json (which would be null if the map returned was empty) and then that tries to parse the package id from the name (which, again, is null) which then checks if it is null (and it is!) so it fails.

So, a bad/corrupt/wrong-format archive would cause this error exactly as it has manifest for you.  This would be a clear error if they failed upon parsing, but instead they simply return an empty map and let the failures come from incidental things down the road... bad design.